# remote AutoIt mouse control script not executed

Tags: android, automation, autoit

my goal is to run a script on a Windows 7 with OpenSSH from an Android device, that will control the cursor. I have written an AutoIt script and compiled it into an exe on the pc (tested it from the cmd, and it works).

the problem is, when i log in from the android and test using ConnectBot (simply run the script), it doesn't do anything. console debugging shows nothing as if all was successful. I have tried running other compiled AutoIt scripts for file creation for example, and they work fine.

can someone explain to me why this happens and what can be done? i suspect environment variables issues here, but don't know what can be done.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

ok found out the reason-openssh doesnt provide gui apps control. found a workaround invoking psexec from ssh, and using it to activate the mouse control script.

Comment: Interesting problem/solution. You should post some more details in your question/answer (e.g. some code) so that it might be of any use for others.

Comment: to sum up- for situation when you want to execute gui scripts remotely (e.g. opening non-console apps without the need to see them, moving cursor, pressing keys) on windows machines (without the headache of x server) place psexec tool on the windows, and wrap the script-calling into "psexec <host> ... -i <call to gui script>", then call the command via an ssh channel.

Comment: You can edit your answer and put the details there. ;-) Oh and you an also accept your own answer.

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is that OpenSSH does not provide control for non-console apps, a clean solution would be to compile your script as a console application.

```
C:\Users\Linus> Aut2exe.exe /in yourscript.au3 /console
```